# What the meaning of TFRP in mobx?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx

I know the FRP(Functional Reactive Programming) meaning, but I was reading The Mobx documentation and I faced to TFRP and I did't understand what it is exactly!
so what is TFRP meaning???

Comment: You can check this thread https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx/issues/220